# id attribute in fragments

Tags: android, xml, fragment

I am working on a app and it runs just fine but there is an problem that it crashes when I dont write id in my fragment code but runs fine after using id attribute and the problem is that i have not used it's id anywhere in my app

**Here is the xml file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
 <fragment
  class="com.hfad.workout.WorkoutList"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:id="@+id/listfrag"
  />
 <FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:text="second text view"
  android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
  android:id="@+id/fragcont"
  android:layout_weight="3"
  />
  </LinearLayout>
```

**workoutlist.jav**

```
 public class WorkoutList extends ListFragment {

    MainActivity ma;
 static interface WorkoutListListener{
 void clickme(long at);
 }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayAdapter<Workout> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Workout>(
                inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
  Workout.workout);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context ac){
        super.onAttach(ac);
        this.ma =(MainActivity) getActivity();

    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView v, View vi, int position, long id){
        ma.clickme(id);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because if you do not specify fragment id, then FragmentManager cannot restore it after recreating.
You have to specify fragment id or tag.

Comment: so,it will never run or it is happening just in my case?

Comment: @ankitjoshi what is the log message, when app crashes

Comment: i don't remember but it is like error in xml binary file at line...and inflator error.... i'm not sure because i have used id attribute after that

Comment: @ankitjoshi anyway if you have no id then fragment manager won't be able to restore it so you should add it.

Comment: @ankitjoshi possibly you can set tag attribute and it will work too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Before an activity can talk to its fragment, the activity first needs
to get a reference to it. To get a reference to the fragment, you first
get a reference to the activity’s **fragment manager** using the
activity’s `getFragmentManager()` method. You then use its
`findFragmentById()` method to get a reference to the fragment:

> `findFragmentById()` is a
>   bit like `findViewById()`
>   except you use it to get a
>   reference to a fragment

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id)
```

Comment: @ neha but in my app i am not using(R.id.listfrag)?

Comment: @ ankit joshi can you show your `WorkoutList.java` code

Comment: are you using `implements WorkoutListFragment.WorkoutListListener` in `MainActivity`

Comment: This is the reason?? @priya jain

Comment: If you look back at the fragment lifecycle, you’ll see that when the fragment is attached to the activity, the fragment’s `onAttach()` method is called with the value of the activity. If you do not define `ID` how would activity know it

Comment: So,this mean whenever we use a fragment in a activity,the id attribute is mandatory and used by activity to recognize which fragment is attached to it,am i right??? Or there is something else @priya jain??please tell